# Rename column of dataframe from 0 to a string (rename not working)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following

|  | index | 0 | feature2 | feature3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | zipcode | 0.10 | y | z |
| 1 | latitude | 0.56 | y | z |
| 2 | longitude | 0.39 | y | z |

I have used the following code to change the 0, the third column name to something else, but when I output the dataframe again nothing has changed and the column is still 0.

```
df.rename(index = {0: 'feature_rank'})
# Or alternatively
df.rename(column = {0: 'feature_rank'})
```

I would also like to know if it is possible to change the name of the second column to something else. Once again rename is not working for the 'index' column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DataFrame.rename()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) returns you a new dataframe with the columns renamed (this is usefull when doing method-chaining).

You want to keep the result by doing:

```py
df = df.rename(column={0: 'feature_rank'})
```

Alternatively it has an argument (called `inplace`) that allows you to do the operation in place (so you wouldn't need to re-assign):

```py
df.rename(column={0: 'feature_rank'}, inplace=True)
```

If you want to rename multiple columns you can just add them to the dictionary, e.g.:

```py
df = df.rename(column={0: 'feature_rank', 'feature2': 'my_new_name_for_feature2'})
```

### Note

About using `df.rename(index=...)` vs. `df.rename(columns=...)` those would have different results. Setting the `index` parameter would rename the rows, setting the `columns` parameter would instead rename the columns.

E.g.:

```py
df = df.rename(column={0: 'feature_rank'})
```

|  | index | feature_rank | feature2 | feature3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | zipcode | 0.10 | y | z |
| 1 | latitude | 0.56 | y | z |
| 2 | longitude | 0.39 | y | z |

Instead:

```py
df = df.rename(index={0: 'feature_rank'})
```

|  | index | 0 | feature2 | feature3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| feature_rank | zipcode | 0.10 | y | z |
| 1 | latitude | 0.56 | y | z |
| 2 | longitude | 0.39 | y | z |

Comment: Thanks! Using inplace = True worked for both of my problems.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will work.

df.rename(columns = {'0':'feature_rank'}, inplace = True)

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

```
df.rename(column={'0':'feature_rank', 'feature2': 'my_new_name_for_feature2'}, inplace=True)
```